# I want to be able to access a particular key within a json object response returned in postgres using node js and express

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

The code :- app.post('/BSK', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
client.query(`Select * from public."mst_bskServices" where "Name" = '${req.body.Service}'`, (err, result)=>{
if(!err){
res.end(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.rows)));
}
else{ console.log(err.message) };
});
client.end;
});

This is the response :-
[
{
id: 1,
Name: 'Aikyashree

```
                                                                                                                                           ',
statusapiurl: 'https://serv1.wbmdfcscholarship.org/Api/bsk_submit_report


                                                                                                                                                   ',   
statusapidoctype: 'DEMO                                              '
```

}
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access id from your response you can perform:results[0].id;
And name: `results[0].name`

And if you have multiple records to access records use for loop over the result key as follows:

`for (var a = 0; a < Object.keys(result).length; a++) { result[a].id result[a].name }`